# Get last row for given dates if date doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How can we query a set of records to get data for particular dates where there might be gaps in dates.

Example Data

```
date       | Price
------------------
2018-03-31 | 115
2018-03-29 | 114
2018-03-28 | 113
...
2017-03-29 | 117
2017-03-28 | 118
...
2016-12-30 | 143
2016-12-29 | 140
...
2015-12-31 | 110
2015-12-30 | 111
```

Required Data for dates: 2018-03-31, 2017-03-31, 2016-12-31, 2015-12-31

```
date       | Price
------------------
2018-03-31 | 115
2017-03-31 | 117
2016-12-31 | 143
2015-12-31 | 110
```

Comment: This looks like a combination of GROUP BY statement for getting the latest price and IN operator for selection the specific dates

Comment: What is the form of `Required Data for dates`? An input table (array of date), a string seperated date values?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach input is array of dates.

Comment: And what is the logic behind your desired output ? To get max price against end of specific months of specific years or I missed it ?

Comment: @codtex seems like if exact date is not present fall back to the nearest prior date.

Comment: @SalmanA output looks as you said and I guess this is the logic of the OP. Your solution for the purpose looks very clean and beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with correlated sub query. The following will return the price for the exact date or the closest prior date:

```
SELECT dates.dt, (
    SELECT price
    FROM t
    WHERE date <= dates.dt
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS price
FROM (
    SELECT '2018-03-31' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-03-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-12-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-12-31'
) AS dates
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=052834e89434bf80961b69eeb5330216)

Comment: This will be quite slow as compared to `IN` operator.

Comment: @iamrajshah how exactly would you do it with the _IN_ operator?

Comment: @SalmanA This is very very smart and efficient. I learned a new hack to loop in SQL. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL Last day function and date_format to achieve the desired result. Check out the query :-

```
select last_day(a11.d_date), a11.price
from test a11
join
(select MAX(d_date) d_date, DATE_FORMAT(d_date, "%M %Y")
from test
group by DATE_FORMAT(d_date, "%M %Y")
) a12
on a11.d_date = a12.d_date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/674ff9/5)

Answer (score 0):

seem you need the max  price for year

```
select max(date), max(price)
from my_table  m 
inner join  (

  select max(date), year(date) my_year
  from my_table 
  group by year(date) 

) t on t.my_year = year(m.date) 
group by year(m.date)
```